# The identity monad as a free monad

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, category-theory, free-monad

The functor of the identity monad can be defined as:

```
data Identity a = Identity a
```

Because this monad is free, an alternative definition is the following:

```
data Term f a = Pure a | Impure (f (Term f a))

data Zero a

type IdentityF a = Term Zero a
```

Since this is the same monad defined in two ways, they shoud be
convertible into each other. That is to say that one should be able to define two
functions `f :: Identity a -> IdentityF a` and `g :: IdentityF a -> Identity a` such that their compositions `f . g` and `g . f` are
identities. The function `f` is easy to define:

```
f :: Identity a -> IdentityF a
f (Identity a) = Pure a
```

But what about the function `g`?

```
g :: IdentityF a -> Identity a
g (Pure a) = Identity a
g (Impure x) = ??????
```

What should be the value of `g (Impure x)`. I could try to cheat and say it
is `undefined` but then `f . g` would not be the identity function and
`Identity` and `IdentityF` would not be isomorphic.

Comment: Don't confuse the type constructor with the functor/monad that *includes* the type constructor. The free monad construction uses something of kind `Type -> Type` that may or may not be a have a `Functor` instance to produce one that *does* have a `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suitable definition is:

```
g (Impure x) = case x of
```

There are no branches in the `case`. This was not a typo. There are exactly as many branches in the case as there are constructors in `Zero a`, as required; this is a complete pattern match.

(You must turn on the `EmptyCase` extension for GHC to accept this as-is.)

Comment: is this different from defining `g (Impure x) = undefined`, and if so, how? I tried both in GHCi and didn't see any difference.

Comment: @WillNess Operationally, they differ only on distinct bottom values, I think. Your definition, called as `g (error "urk")` will trigger the `undefined` exception. Daniel's one, on the same call, will trigger the "urk" exception. I don't know if this is guaranteed, I only made a quick test. IIRC, GHC sometimes optimizes assuming any bottom value is equivalent to the others, so perhaps it is _not_ guaranteed which exception we get.

Comment: @WillNess At the level of communication, it's different. It says 1) I'm using `x` and 2) I'm matching all patterns for `x`. This reads very differently than 1) I'm ignoring the argument to `Impure` and 2) I'm introducing a new bottom here. It says a lot more to the reader about why the author believes the code is valid.

Comment: @WillNess If you consider all bottoms equal, it is the same. If you allow yourself to notice differences, then it's probably something more like ```g (Impure x) = x `seq` undefined```; e.g. try passing in an infinite loop. However, chi is also correct: the language spec allows ```x `seq` undefined``` to return either `x` or `undefined` if both are bottoms, so you probably should not rely on this.

Comment: Thanks to all for commenting. I just used `undefined` in my testing but indeed there's  more nuance possible here.